# Howto get access to another controller/view (iOS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, controller

I have three separated class, UIViewController (A) and two UITableViewControllers (B and C).

I add table B and C into A.

```
[A.view addSubview:B.tableView];

[A.view addSubview:C.tableView];
```

Now I need to change/reload one table by the selection in another table. For example, select "meat" in B then C become "chicken, pork...", select "fruit" then get "apple, tomato...".

My question is generally Howto get access to another controller/view. What should I write in didSelectRowAtIndexPath in B to access another controller (A, C)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [delegation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). Add a protocol to B and C and let the other implement it.

I wrote a [sample code](https://github.com/vikingosegundo/my-programming-examples/tree/master/VSCheckFavorites) quite along time ago.

In there the CheckTableController can inform the ShowFavoritesTableController, as the second implements the delegate protocol of the first.

Comment: Thanks @vikingosegundo. what is the difference between delegation and notification in this case, in a view of programming principles. I think their principles are quite similar, which are let someone else to do it for them.

Comment: There are similarities. But big differences as well. Notifications do broadcasting: They can inform many objects, that "tuned-in" on an object, but their sender can't receive any message or objects from it listeners. Delegations is a 1-to-1 communication, but the delegate methods can return objects. You are free to use methods with signatures of any kind. Notification broadcasting is expensive, while delegations is just normal message sending.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this through the NSNotificationCenter. In the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

broadcast a message using NotificationCenter.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"NotificationName" object:myObj];
```

On the class that has the receiving end set it to listen for this notification in the viewDidLoad or init method

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable:) name:@"NotificationName" object:nil];
```

Have your method declared in the .m file

```
-(void)reloadTable:(NSNotification*)n {
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

Remember to remove the observer when the object is destroyed in the dealloc method
If you're using ARC

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

If you're not using ARC remember to super

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Justin. This seems a good way to do it. Lets see if there are other ways. Just want to know the best method.

Comment: I also like @asops's strategy for handling multiple table views in the same class. I have also done that before and it works well. Sometimes I switch which table is which by setting the tableView's tag(int) property so I don't have to hold weak references to the tableView when using Interface Builder. The notification center way works well when you are talking across objects and don't want to force rigidity into the structure of your code. In addition, you don't have to worry about retain cycles this way.

Comment: Notifications are considered expensive. They are good for situations, where you can't know, if any (or many) objects need to be informed — and if they exists yet. also they can be used, if you pass informations from a distance part of your application to another  instead of using a custom singleton. But the question does not describe such a scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is, instead of using three separate controllers, just to use one.  This one controller will be a subclass of `UIViewController`, and its `.h` file should look something like this:

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
    UITableView *firstTableView;
    UITableView *secondTableView;
@end
```

Now, in your `.m` file, set the tables up like so:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        firstTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:/*desired frame*/ style:/*desired style*/];
        secondTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:/*desired frame*/ style:/*desired style*/];

        firstTableView.delegate = self;
        firstTableView.dataSource = self;

        secondTableView.delegate = self;
        secondTableView.dataSource = self;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [firstTableView release];
    [secondTableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then, implement desired `UITableViewDataSource` methods like so:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == firstTableView) {
        // Do something
    } else if (tableView == secondTableView) {
        // Do something else
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if (tableView == firstTableView) {
        // Configure the cell
    } else if (tableView == secondTableView) {
        // Configure the cell a different way
    }
}
```

Finally, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (tableView == firstTableView) {
        // Update something that is linked to the return values of secondTableView's dataSource methods
        [secondTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

This approach ensures that your controller gets the right `-viewDidLoad`, `-viewWillAppear`, and so on, automatically.  Remember, **just adding view controller's views as subviews means that your controller will not receive these calls.**

Comment: Personally I think, this is a very messy way, as you will have to maintain a jungle of if/else-statements.

Comment: Thanks @aopsfan, a huge class is powerful, but also hard to maintain, use it with care

Comment: I agree with the idea that only one view controller should be used (OF COURSE!), but I think it is best to create separate files for each tableview that handles the approprate datasource/delegate methods.

Comment: @aopsfan **just adding view controller's views as subviews means that your controller will not receive these calls** - is there other ways to add those table in? for example, add the controller B and C in A so they can access to each other?

Comment: @ThinkChris Yes, there is.  I'll add another answer for this solution when I get the time.  Note that it is iOS5 specific.

Comment: I think this is the worst way.